# Best practice with user permission?

Tags: permissions, user-management, restricted-access

When adding new users to my server, I want them to have their own /home/ dir, and also /home/user/www/ which is linked from their own apache html folder. No other user should be able to view those files.

At the same time I dont want to restrict them from the basic  trusted user shell commands. This is how it is today, but, the question: how do I manage this, without giving access to config / os files?  I dont like users being able to read the diverse files lying around.

Should I add a group for those users which restricts specific dirs and files? Or change permission for those files? Are there any other way? I have been looking at chrootjail, but it restricts too much functionality. How do host providers solve this?

Best scenario would be to have them see home as root.

Comment: Use userdir http://www.techytalk.info/enable-userdir-apache-module-ubuntu-debian-based-linux-distributions/

Comment: That solves the personal web dir, but not restrict anyone looking at e.g: / or /var/..

Comment: There is no easy way to manage system files beyond the default setup. If you need that look at LXC or docker